# Change eclipse Help home page

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We are developing RCP application. 
Recently we have implemented eclipse help in our application, using TOC we have integrated all html pages in help but we are facing one issue.

In help dialog, default page is eclipse default html page(help introduction), i have seen in eclipse help customization tutorial that it is defined in following way:
help_home=/org.eclipse.help/doc/help_home.html

I have tried to add this property in `plugin_customization.ini` but no success.

Please guide me, how to override default eclipse help page displayed while launching help dialog?

Additionally is there any way to support this page for multiple languages, as it is currently supporting english page and translation plugin for help does not contain this page.

Comment: Is your page properly included in one of your plugins and referenced from .ini? Did you define proper extension for the .ini file?

Comment: Yes, it is included and now i am able to see my own page in html by providing field org.eclipse.help.base/help_home in ini file. but it is always showing in english, Is there any way to provide support for multiple language for this? I can not find anyway to support this page for language other than english?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include the plugin id that owns the preference when specifying preference values in the `plugin_customization.ini` file. `help_home` belongs to the `org.eclipse.help.base` plugin so the format is:

```
org.eclipse.help.base/help_home=/pluginId/path/to/home.html
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. It works :) but as it is hard coded path to html page so is there any way to change this page based on language change i.e for english it displays html english page and for german it will display html page having german langauge contents?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Help NLS support.